# L'espressione "in barba a" può significare "nonostante"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Su [questo articolo di Euronews](http://it.euronews.com/2017/01/21/trump-in-visita-al-quartier-generale-della-cia-sconfiggeremo-il-terrorismo/) ho letto:

> Elogi a dismisura sono stati dispensati dal magnate, **in barba alle** accuse da lui stesso mosse, appena pochi giorni orsono, proprio nei confronti dell’Intelligence.

Non conoscevo il significato dell'espressione "in barba a", quindi l'ho cercata su alcuni dizionari. Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/barba1/) ho trovato

> *fare qualcosa in b. a uno*, a suo dispetto e scapito;

e le definizioni che ho letto sugli altri dizionari sono simili. Tuttavia, ho pensato che, nel contesto del brano sopra citato, "in barba a" potesse significare "nonostante", "malgrado". È così? Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire questo mio dubbio?

Comment: È molto vicino a *nonostante*, ma c'è una leggera connotazione di "fare un dispetto a".

Comment: @DenisNardin:  Ma come si può "fare un dispetto alle accuse da lui stesso mosse"? Penso di non capire bene il senso di questa espressione.

Comment: Più che “dispetto” nel senso che ha in “fare un dispetto”, c'è il senso antiquato di “superiorità sdegnosa o di ostentata noncuranza” (vedi [qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dispetto2)) dell'espressione “a dispetto di”. E se consideriamo “in barba a” come sinonimo di “a dispetto di”, ci siamo: Trump ostenta superiorità e noncuranza.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Come è stato ricordato, i vocabolari considerano “in barba a” più o meno come sinonimo di “a dispetto di”; in quest'ultima espressione “dispetto” non ha il senso che ha in “fare un dispetto”, ma quello antiquato di “superiorità sdegnosa o di ostentata noncuranza” (vedi [qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dispetto2)), coerentemente con il contesto citato: Trump ostenta superiorità e noncuranza.

Quanto a “in barba”, il *Dizionario dei modi di dire della lingua italiana* di Carlo Lapucci ne spiega l'origine come «‘proprio sotto gli occhi’ o ‘quasi davanti alla barba’, modo di dire che l'uso ha esteso e riferito impropriamente anche alla donna».

Answer (score 1):

***[In barba a](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/in-barba-a)***  nella frase ha il significato di "a scapito di, a dispetto di".

L'uso dell'espressione crea un effetto di sorpresa e forse di critica rispetto agli elogi fatti dal  magnate dopo aver mosso delle accuse.

(De Mauro)

Comment: ho trovato questa spiegazione dell'origine di questo modo di dire: http://paginedipergamena.blogspot.it/2013/04/perche-si-dice-farla-in-barba.html

Comment: Penso sia interessante aggiungere quello che ha detto @DaG sul significato di "a dispetto di" nel contesto del brano.